# Pyodbc insert of large number fails int to big to convert when inserting into Sql Server using Oracle cursor

Tags: python, sql-server, oracle, pyodbc

I am trying to do an executemany with an insert into a SQL Server using an Oracle cursor like this:

```
sqlservercursor.executemany("INSERT INTO tablename (col1,col2...) VALUES (?,?…)",oraclecursor)
```

This fails with error:`OverflowError: int too big to convert`

I have diagnosed it to the id columns which are large numbers(NUMBER(25)).

I can reproduce this using:

```
sqlservercursor.execute('INSERT INTO tablename (Id) VALUES (?)',(90100111000002885322904,))
```

however this works:

```
sqlservercursor.execute('INSERT INTO tablename (Id) VALUES (90100111000002885322904)')
```

Is there a way fix this or must I loop through the cursor and insert manually?  This would be slow compared to pyodbc's fast execute as well as having to deal with characters...

Comment: Why are you using a oracle cursor for a SQL Server instance?

Comment: I have to transfer an Oracle DB to SQL Server. That being said, this problem would persist SQL Server to SQL Server if you had a Decimal(38) number I believe or if I just wanted to add large numbers using params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and work around it using [fast_executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany):

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=mssqlLocal64")
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("CREATE TABLE ##tablename (Id decimal(25,0))")
data = [(90100111000002885322904,)]  # list of tuple(s)
sql = "INSERT INTO ##tablename (Id) VALUES (?)"
crsr.fast_executemany = True
crsr.executemany(sql, data)
```

Comment: This works for the coded version but when I feed the executemany the Oracle cursor I still receive the error. I pulled 1 row, gave an error, then converted that row to a list of a tuple and inserted it that way and it worked so its something to do with the cursor.  Any idea how to fix that? If not I would have to convert the cursor row by row to a tuple?  Thanks

Comment: Be careful with terminology. "Cursor" has a specific meaning in the context of a DBAPI application. I suspect what you have is a "result set" which is typically a list of tuples, but can also be a list of tuple-like objects. In any case, you could try pickling your single-row `oraclecursor` object (the one that causes the error) to a file and post a download link for it so others could try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have it working now. I used oraclecursor.fetchall() in the paramaters(creates a list of tuples). A couple of tables throw a memory error, I suspect I need to use clumps instead of all.  Thanks for your help once again:)